# What is MessageDigest doing when you do MessageDigest.update more than once?

Tags: java, c#

I have a Java method that I'm porting to C# which hashes a string using a salt. The method is does something like the following.

```
private byte[] hash(byte[] bytes, byte[] salt) {
    MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digester.update(salt);
    digester.update(bytes);
    byte[] hashed = digester.digest();
    return hashed;
}
```

What I don't get is what the double update function is doing. Is it actually doing anything?

> This question was reposted becauase it was wrongfully marked as duplicate. I found an answer and decided to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between MessageDigest in Java and HashAlgorithm in c# is that MessageDigest is stateful while HashAlgorithm isn't. When calling MessageDigest.update, you're appending the byte array provided to the byte array within MessageDigest. This resets when MessageDigest.digest is called.

In c#, since the HashAlgorith isn't stateful, it just hashes whatever is provided. The equivalent c# method to the hash function in the question would be the following...

```
private byte[] Hash(byte[] bytes, byte[] salt)
{   
    HashAlgorithm sha256 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] combined = salt.Concat(bytes).ToArray();
    byte[] hashed = sha256.ComputeHash(combined);
    return hashed;
}
```